# SML - Creating dictionary that maps keys to values

Tags: function, dictionary, key, sml

I need to create a dictionary in sml, but I am having extreme difficulty with an insert function.

```
    type dict = string -> int option
```

As an example, here is the empty dictionary:

```
    val empty : dict = fn key => NONE
```

Here is my implementation of an insert function:

```
    fun insert (key,value) d = fn d => fn key => value
```

But this is of the wrong type, what I need is     insert : (string*int) -> dict -> dict.
I've searched everything from lazy functions to implementing dictionaries.
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciateds!

If you are still confused on what I am trying to implement, I drafted up what I should expect to get when calling a simple lookup function

```
    fun lookup k d = d k

    - val d = insert ("foo",2) (insert ("bar",3) empty);
    val d = fn : string -> int option
    - lookup2 "foo" d;
    val it = SOME 2 : int option
    - lookup2 "bar" d;
    val it = SOME 3 : int option
    - lookup2 "baz" d;
    val it = NONE : int option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reason on the signature of the function:

```
val insert = fn: (string * int) -> dict -> dict
```

When you supply `key`, `value` and a dictionary `d`, you would like to get back a new dictionary `d'`. Since `dict` is `string -> int option`, `d'` is a function takes a `string` and returns an `int option`.

Suppose you supply a string `s` to that function. There are two cases which could happen: when `s` is the same as `key` you return the associated value, otherwise you return a value by looking up `d` with key `s`.

Here is a literal translation:

```
fun insert (key, value) d = fn s => if s = key then SOME value
                                    else d s
```