# Creating A Dictionary In SML

Tags: dictionary, sml, smlnj, metalanguage

I am newly Learner Of The SML Language. I Have Learned The Basics Of SML Language.But, I am having a Trouble In getting the code of creating a dictionary in SML. So, I Want To Know The code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SML - Creating dictionary that maps keys to values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507516/sml-creating-dictionary-that-maps-keys-to-values)

Comment: Yatendra: I suggest you look at the Q&A that snieguu links to, since it contains more or less your question, except with code that reflects an attempt to make one. Making an attempt before asking is generally preferred, as well as looking for previously asked questions on the same subject. (This can typically be accomplished by Googling.)

Comment: You can write such a thing in many ways - there's no "the" code. What to do depends a lot on what you're learning at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by defining a signature for your dictionary:

```ml
signature DICT =
sig
  type (''k, 'v) dict

  val empty : (''k, 'v) dict
  val insert : ''k -> 'v -> (''k, 'v) dict -> (''k, 'v) dict
  val lookup : ''k -> (''k, 'v) dict -> 'v option
end
```

The `''k` (an equality type) assumes that the only thing I need to know about the key of a key-value store is that it can be compared for equality, so that I can find the right key when looking. This allows me to build a simple list-based dictionary with *O(n)* insert and lookup:

```ml
structure ListDict : DICT =
struct
  type (''k, 'v) dict = (''k * 'v) list

  val empty = []

  fun insert k v [] = [(k, v)]
    | insert k v ((k2,v2) :: rest) =
      if k = k2 then (k,v) :: rest else (k2,v2) :: insert k v rest

  fun lookup k [] = NONE
    | lookup k ((k2, v) :: rest) =
      if k = k2 then SOME v else lookup k rest
end
```

The type-level restriction of `''k` means that I can't, for example, represent my dictionary as a binary search tree, since ordering things (less than, equal to, greater than) is not a property of equality types, or represent my dictionary as a hashtable, since finding the hash of a value is also not a property of equality types.

So I might instead like that keys can be ordered or hashed. Unfortunately SML does not have a built-in class of types that are orderable or hashable like it has equality types. A way to overcome this limitation is to change the interface so that a comparison or hash function is passed to the module. Here's how that might look for comparison:

```ml
signature ORD =
sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> order
end

signature DICT =
sig
  type k
  type 'v dict

  val empty : 'v dict
  val insert : k -> 'v -> 'v dict -> 'v dict
  val lookup : k -> 'v dict -> 'v option
end
```

This allows me, for example, to write a dictionary structure based on binary trees:

```ml
functor TreeDict (Ord : ORD) : DICT =
struct
  type k = Ord.t
  datatype 'v dict = Leaf | Node of k * 'v * 'v dict * 'v dict

  val empty = Leaf

  fun insert k v Leaf = Node (k, v, Leaf, Leaf)
    | insert k v (Node (k2, v2, left, right)) =
      case Ord.compare (k, k2) of
           EQ => Node (k, v, left, right)
         | LT => Node (k2, v2, insert k v left, right)
         | GT => Node (k2, v2, left, insert k v right)

  fun lookup k Leaf = NONE
    | lookup k (Node (k2, v, left, right)) =
      case Ord.compare (k, k2) of
           EQ => SOME v
         | GT => lookup k right
         | LT => lookup k left
end
```

The downside is that I have to be specific about what `ORD` I want.

E.g. a tree-based dictionary where the key is `int` may be made like this:

```ml
structure IntTreeDict = TreeDict(
  struct
    type t = int
    val compare = Int.compare
  end)
```